# mongo db aggregate keep fields after group

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have this aggregate:

```
[
    {
        $match: {_id: new ObjectId('xxx')}
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$users"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$users.status',
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            name: 1,
            field1: 1,
            field2: 1,
            count: '$count'
        }
    }
]
```

The schema:

```
{
    name: String,
    field1: String,
    field2: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    users: [{
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        status: String
    }]
}
```

The expected result:

```
{
    name: 'NY',
    field1: 'example',
    field2: 'example2',
    statuses: [
        {
            _id: 'ONLINE',
            count: 20
        },
        {
            _id: 'OFFLINE',
            count: 120
        },
        {
            _id: 'OTHER',
            count: 230
        }
    ]
}
```

This way I get group result just for the users statuses, and not for the other fields of the original object.

Comment: can you please add a little more explanation about what you exactly need ?

Comment: could you provide an example of a document from the collection, and how you would like the output to appear?

Comment: Sure: I have city document, with name of the city and other data, and also an array of users. I want to project all the fields, and also group by the users statuses and project it also

Comment: The point here is "which values should those actually be?". Because your grouping key comes from `"users.status"` and that is going to to traverse "multiple documents". So you are asking to retain fields from the document, but the grouping means it would be more than one possible value for each. So which one is it supposed to be? You should be showing "sample input documents" and an "expected result" from that sample. That makes your intention clearer than by simply showing a schema.

Comment: I edited the question